# How to create two different cache definition for single path based on header

Tags: nginx

How to create two different cache definition for single path based on header. If there is a header present in the request then it should use proxy_cache Answers but if there is no header

```
        location /answers {
         # Check if the x-amzn-waf-google-crawler exists
        if ($http_x_amzn_waf_google_crawler) {
            proxy_cache Answers;
            proxy_pass $bncFrontendAlb;
        }
        # Use the second proxy cache when x-amzn-waf-google-crawler is not there
        if ($http_x_amzn_waf_google_crawler = "") {
            proxy_cache Answers_bot;
            proxy_pass $bncFrontendAlb;
        }
    }
```

I am getting error

```
nginx: [emerg] "proxy_cache" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:40
```